# How to send system notifications for windows in golang

Tags: windows, go, notifications

I want to send a system notifications to windows using golang.

How can this be done?
if you awnser contains a cross platform solution it would be even better.

Comment: What are "system notifications" ? write events in a journal ?

Comment: small info popups from OS notification tray, i think growl does that for mac

Comment: https://github.com/go-toast/toast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding system notification with Golang in 2020 and found this: https://github.com/gen2brain/beeep . It looks like currently still actively maintained.

Example from repo:

```
err := beeep.Notify("Title", "Message body", "assets/information.png")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Even it works great, actually I feel that this app was made mainly for producing "beep" sound on the computer speaker. Based on the app name which is "beeep" :). You can check on example page if interest in makes those "beep" sound too.

Comment: Thank you :-) i love beep sounds :-)

Comment: Great to know :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are looking for desktop notifications.  There are a few different libraries that can do this for you.  **Originally I found this with a simple Google search**

Link / Dependency URL:  [github.com/0xAX/notificator](https://github.com/0xAX/notificator)

Here is the example on their README.md page:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/0xAX/notificator"
)

var notify *notificator.Notificator

func main() {

  notify = notificator.New(notificator.Options{
    DefaultIcon: "icon/default.png",
    AppName:     "My test App",
  })

  notify.Push("title", "text", "/home/user/icon.png", notificator.UR_CRITICAL)
}
```